# Why SSRS use Share point server for deployment of reports?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, sharepoint

I switched from Oracle platform to Microsoft SSRS.

Currently I am working on SSRS.
What is the use of Share point server for deployment of SSRS reports ?

Comment: You have three different installation options: installed and configured, with sharepoint, installed but not configured. Did you not want sharepoint configuration? If so you can install without.

Comment: Why we need share point server for SSRS ?

Comment: You don't. There has been an integration option since SQL 2008 (or thereabouts).

Comment: Ok..What is the benefit or feature we can use when i configure share point server for SSRS ?

Comment: Basically if your planning on using Sharepoint, then install it.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326358(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Technet has a decent article. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326358(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: For deployment of SSRS report i am going to use ASP.NET for calling report file..so that share point is important or not ?

Comment: No. It's only important if your actually wanting to use Sharepoint.